# Preselect table values in the system configuration

Tags: magento2, system.xml, system-config

I used [this example](http://www.ibnab.com/en/blog/magento-2/magento-2-backend-guide-to-create-table-setting-in-the-system-configuration) to create my own table with configuration in admin. Now I'm trying to figure out how to preselect my saved values on page loads. I have this table now:

[image]

For preselecting this example uses `_prepareArrayRow()`

This is value from core_config _data:

```
a:4:{s:18:"_1486995392381_381";a:3:{s:12:"m2_attribute";s:16:"required_options";s:13:"chq_attribute";s:14:"CustomDecimal1";s:9:"push_once";s:5:"false";}s:18:"_1486995402858_858";a:3:{s:12:"m2_attribute";s:14:"fabric_content";s:13:"chq_attribute";s:6:"Rental";s:9:"push_once";s:4:"true";}s:18:"_1486995407176_176";a:3:{s:12:"m2_attribute";s:9:"fabricfit";s:13:"chq_attribute";s:13:"CustomNumber3";s:9:"push_once";s:4:"true";}s:17:"_1486995414029_29";a:3:{s:12:"m2_attribute";s:17:"short_description";s:13:"chq_attribute";s:17:"ItemCustomNumber6";s:9:"push_once";s:5:"false";}}
```

This is how unserialized value looks like:

```
Array
(
    [_1486995392381_381] => Array
        (
            [m2_attribute] => required_options
            [chq_attribute] => CustomDecimal1
            [push_once] => false
        )

    [_1486995402858_858] => Array
        (
            [m2_attribute] => fabric_content
            [chq_attribute] => Rental
            [push_once] => true
        )

    [_1486995407176_176] => Array
        (
            [m2_attribute] => fabricfit
            [chq_attribute] => CustomNumber3
            [push_once] => true
        )

    [_1486995414029_29] => Array
        (
            [m2_attribute] => short_description
            [chq_attribute] => ItemCustomNumber6
            [push_once] => false
        )

)
```

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: Can you post this Json value from `core_config_data` here?

Comment: a:4:{s:18:"_1486995392381_381";a:3:{s:12:"test1";s:16:"required_options";s:13:"test2";s:14:"CustomDecimal1";s:9:"test3";s:5:"false";}s:18:"_1486995402858_858";a:3:{s:12:"test1";s:14:"fabric_content";s:13:"test2";s:6:"Rental";s:9:"test3";s:4:"true";}s:18:"_1486995407176_176";a:3:{s:12:"test1";s:9:"fabricfit";s:13:"test2";s:13:"CustomNumber3";s:9:"test3";s:4:"true";}s:17:"_1486995414029_29";a:3:{s:12:"test1";s:17:"short_description";s:13:"test2";s:17:"ItemCustomNumber6";s:9:"test3";s:5:"false";}}

Comment: Let's try on this example: [["old_id","CustomText1",true],["new_id","CustomText2",false],["custom","CustomText3",true]]

Comment: I need the value from your `core_config_data`, because, I want to make sure the saved value is corrected. I think your issue is hard to debug because your custom code is not available. It's better if you post your module on Github or here.

Answer (score 1):

Finally I figured out how to make it. I created repo and you can check test module [there](https://github.com/oroskodias/table-test). The answer for this question is in file `Block/System/Config/Form/Field/Active.php` in method `_prepareArrayRow()`